# Attaching a WYSIWYG Library to a Dynamically Generated Input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, wysiwyg

In a VUE.JS 2 application I'm working on, there is a series of form fields dynamically generated from a JSON Schema. As the Schemas change so do the inputs. (We are using a modified version of this library : https://gitlab.com/formschema/native/tree/feature/new-architecture.

I'd like to attach a Basic WYSIWYG to a particular textarea that was dynamically generated. All the libraries I've come accross need you to manually add the Tag to the template with attributes. Since the form is dynamically generated this seems difficult to do.

Is there a simpler vuejs way to attach a WYSIWYG Editor to a textarea? Perhaps by linking it to a certain ID. The textarea comes prepopulated with data from an API, and that info would need to be included. Any insight is appreciated. I've looked at the following libraries with no success:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue
- https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg
- https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor

Comment: Can you share your code? I have some ideas for you, but I need to see what the code that generates/updates the form looks like.